# IAdviseSink setup for catching MSWord document events

Tags: delphi, events, ms-word, ole-automation

Here is the code where I try to setup `IAdviseSink` interface implemented in my `TForm1` class for catching some events of the newly created MSWord document. I have not any errors while the code runs, but I can't catch any event, while save the document or close it. 
How-to setup `IAdviseSink` for MSWord document correctly?

```
    var
      Form1 : TForm1;
      doc_ole_obj : IOleObject;
      word : IDispatch;
      Connection: LongInt;

    implementation

     //------------ Setup IAdviseSink
    procedure TForm1.Setup;
    begin
     word := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
     OleVariant(word).Visible := True;

     IUnknown(OleVariant(word).Documents.Open('file.doc')).QueryInterface(IOleObject,doc_ole_obj);
     doc_ole_obj.Advise(IAdviseSink(Self), Connection);
    end;

     //------------- catch Sink events
    procedure TForm1.OnSave;
    begin
      Caption := 'saved at ' + TimeToStr(Now);
    end;
```

Comment: With that setup, OnClose fires here fine when I close the doc, when I save the doc 'OnRename' fires, when I save with a new name again 'OnRename' fires. What gives?

Comment: 'OnClose' example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2886747/243614), but I haven't tested other events then..

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

*Never mind this answer. Leaving it in for eductional purposes.*

---

Why the cast `IAdviseSink(Self)`?

If you declared the interface in the Form's class declaration:

```
TForm1 = class(TForm, IAdviseSink)
   ...
end;
```

, you shouldn't have to.

The fact that you use the cast (and a hard cast which just tells the compiler to shut up), may indicate that you didn't. And that may well cause the dispatch mechanism to find that your form does not implement IAdviseSink and therefore has nothing on which to call the OnSave method.

---

Explanation of why the above is not the issue:

I didn't understood Sertac's comment 'But then the code wouldn't compile' at first. He meant that without `IAdviseSink` being part of the form's class declaration, the line

```
doc_ole_obj.Advise(IAdviseSink(Self), Connection);
```

would cause a [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(41): E2010 Incompatible types: 'IAdviseSink' and 'TForm1'

The `IAdviseSink(Self)` obviously isn't a simple hard cast like `TForm(SomePointer)` is, which basically tells the compiler to shut up and treat SomePointer as a TForm. An interface cast then, prompts the compiler to check whether the instance being cast actually supports the interface. Didn't know that. Learn something new every day.

Comment: @Sertac: Why ever not? It compiles fine on my machine (D2010).

Comment: I didn't mean the cast. If the form had not been implementing IAdviseSink, then `Advise(Self..` would not compile. Neither `Advise(IAdviseSink(Self), ..`, gives *'Incompatible types..'* here.

Comment: @Sertac: Ah, I see what you mean. So an interface cast isn't as hard as I thought... Should start to use interfaces more...

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer, but...

Is there a particular reason why you want to reinvent the wheel and do the whole `Advise`-thing yourself? Why not just use the `TWordDocument` wrapper class from the `Word2000`-unit that comes bundled with Delphi (all you'd have to do in that case would be to call `ConnectTo()` and assign your event handlers)? However, the `Document` object doesn't have an `OnSave` event (at least not in the 2000 version of the TLB, which is generally a good common denominator if you want your app to be compatible with multiple versions of Office). The `Application` object does have a `BeforeDocumentSave`-event, though...